# Get the native socket descriptor from the connection or connection_ptr in websocketpp?

Tags: c++, websocket, boost-asio, websocket++

Is there any way to get the native socket descriptor from the `connection` or `connection_ptr` in `websocketpp`?
I need to set the TCP_CORK before I send the frame to the client. I am new to Boost.Asio please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From following the [github](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp) code, you can likely call 
`connection_ptr->get_raw_socket().native_handle()`.

[`websocketpp::connection`](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/blob/a10b3a1704a05c85289b8701cfe0603815b402fa/src/connection.hpp#L69) inherits from [`websocketpp::socket::connection`](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/blob/db0a43a228346f6e8cff12ea9bbff8ca80cd9bdf/src/sockets/plain.hpp#L68), and `websocket::socket::connection` provides a `get_socket()` public member function that returns a reference to a Boost.Asio socket.  Boost.Asio sockets provide a [`native_handle()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/native_handle.html) member function that returns the native socket representation.

Comment: [WebSocket++ author here] this answer is correct. Two clarifications:
get_raw_socket() is preferred over get_socket(). The code above will work correctly on unsecure connections only. get_socket() on a secure connection will return the TLS stream wrapper. get_raw_socket() will always return the lowest layer (ie the socket itself).

If you are using WebSocket++ 0.3.x, you can register a socket_init_handler that will fire before anything is read/written that you can then use to set socket options before the opening handshake is read/written.